# Will the H-4 EAD applicable for the taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

what are the taxes applicable for the H-4 EAD.
Will s/he are exempt from the SSN/MEDICARE or s/he will applicable to pay the taxes?

Answer (score 2):

No, H4 will not be exempt from FICA taxes.

Comment: @teja Please accept this answer if it meets your needs.